# Mail being rejected, but not with error I would expect

Tags: c#, exchange-server

First the simple mail code:

```
var objMail = new MailMessage(myEmail, myEmail, "Test Message", "Some message");
var objNc = new NetworkCredential("complete", "rubbish");
var objsmtp = new SmtpClient(myExchangeServer") { UseDefaultCredentials = false, Credentials = objNc };
```

I started off with correct credentials and getting this message from exchange:

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Message rejected as spam by Content Filtering.

Exchange problem I thought, but I then tried with bad credentials (user: complete password: rubbish) and I get the same exception.

I would have expected an authentication error, so I suspect I am specifying the credentials incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the email hits the spam filter first, in which case it would be nothing to do with your credentials. Look at the message returned:

> Message rejected as spam by Content Filtering

There are lots of things that can set off an email spam filter. In your case it might be the relatively low text content.

[MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/how-to-avoid-spam-filters/html/) has a decent article on the things spam filters look for.

Note this line in particular:

> Using the word “test” in the subject line (agencies run into this when sending drafts to clients for approval)

I can't remember the `MailMessage` parameter order but it looks like you may be doing this - see `Test Message` as the subject line...

```
var objMail = new MailMessage(myEmail, myEmail, "Test Message", "Some message");
```

Comment: Putting more/more meaningful text in body solved it. Simple as that. Had another problem of not being able to send to same address as from, but got over that, can put what ever I like in from it appears.

Comment: Good stuff, glad this helped

Comment: Also get authentication errors now, so definitely applying spam filter first! I'd have thought as a authenticated user I could send whatever I liked.

Comment: @user2586804 `I'd have thought as a authenticated user I could send whatever I liked` No not at all - what happens if your credentials are compromised? :)

Comment: Dunno, but some spam sent from account would be the least of my concerns I'd imagine!

Answer (score 0):

Set the smtp setting in you app config

```
  <system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="abc@abc.com"  deliveryMethod="Network">
    <network defaultCredentials="true" userName="usernae" password="passo" host="smtp.emailsrvr.com" port="25"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

then for sending mail

```
string toEmail = "reciever Email";
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    var smtpSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp") as System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection;
                    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(Convert.ToString(smtpSection.From), "Mail Header");
                    smtpClient.Host = Convert.ToString(smtpSection.Network.Host);
                    smtpClient.Port = Convert.ToInt32(smtpSection.Network.Port);
                    if (smtpSection.Network.UserName != null && smtpSection.Network.Password != null)
                    {
                        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpSection.Network.UserName, smtpSection.Network.Password);
                    }
                    message.From = fromAddress;
                    message.To.Add(toEmail);
                    message.Subject = "your subject";
                    message.Body = "message body";
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true; // if using html
                    message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    smtpClient.Send(message);
                }
```